# angularJS: auto play video on source/stream change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video

I am using getUserMedia to capture the stream from user camera, so initially the video element source would be null, after successful capture, it set the `src` attribute of video, and call play method the element,

html:

```
...<video></video>...
```

JS code:

```
angular.element('video')[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
angular.element('video')[0].play();
```

I am getting a feeling that this is a bad approach,  I want to something like

html:

```
...<video ng-src="videoObj.src"></video>...
```

JS code:

```
videoObj.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
....
```

now how do I make the video play automatically when I set `videoObj.src` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to set autoplay attribute?

```
<video autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```